# Adding another class to serializer in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I wish to add another class to an existing serializer. I am able to do simple serializers, but this one is rather tricky because the second class I wish to add comes after the serializer's class in the `models.py`- Anybody with a clever solution?

The `models.py` is as follows:

```
class Pokemon(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    type = models.OneToOneField(Type, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    stat = models.ForeignKey(Stat, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True)



class Skills(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    pokemon = models.ForeignKey(Pokemon, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Owner, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='name')
```

and the `serializers.py`:

```
class PokemonSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Pokemon
        fields = ('id', 'type', 'stat')
```

The display that I currently have is:

```
{
    "id": 2228,
    "type": "http://localhost:8000/type/4628/",
    "stat": "99",

}
```

and the display that I am shooting for is:

```
{
    "id": 2228,
    "type": "http://localhost:8000/type/4628/",
    "stat": "99",
    "owner": "bob doe"

}
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: A `Pokemon`'s relationship to `owner` is via `Skills`. From your model design, it looks like a Pokemon can have multiple skills (you access a pokemon's skills via something like `pokemon.skills_set.all()`), which means that it will have multiple owners, not just one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add new serializer called owner for example

```
class Owner(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = skills
        fields = ('owner',)
```

in `PokemonSerializer` add field owner

```
owner = Owner(many=True, read_only=True)
```

You can read further more [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships)

Comment: Hey, thank you for your input. Done that, I did add `copies` to the `fields` as well but it isn't displayed at all.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [source](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source) in the a CharField

```
class PokemonSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

   owner = CharField(source="owner.name")        

    class Meta:
        model = Pokemon
        fields = ('id', 'type', 'stat', 'owner')
```

Comment: This doesn't work - first of all it needs to be `serializers.CharField`. `owner` is not even defined at class `Pokemon` but it is defined on a class that is defined later, which is `Skills`.